# How can I show label on product if saleable quantity is zero?

Tags: magento2

I want to show lable :"out of stock" on product on category page when saleable quantity is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Override in your template or module the file module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml.
After you make changes clean&flush cache

Comment: how can i get saleabale quantity in itms.phtml without using object manager.

Comment: in this file there is a method $_item->isSalable(), this method check that the product has the stock qty and other things. So u can put here your else statement for show your label

Comment: can you write me a working condition plz ? I have implemented many ways.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code in Your Helper Or Create ViewModel(Suggested) :-**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\ModelName\Helper;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
class ClassName
{
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    public function __construct(
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    }
    public function getSalableQuantityBySku($sku)
    {
        $salable = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
        return $salable;
    }
}
```

in phtml use that function

`$this->helper('Vendor\Module\ModelName\Helper\Classname)->getSalableQuantityBySku('test_sku');`

**Output :-**

```
[{"stock_name":"Default Stock","qty":4,"manage_stock":true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create default.phtml in the below path

app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\type\

Now add the below code

```
$_product = $block->getProduct(); 
$stockstate = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface');
$sale_qty = $stockstate->execute($_product->getSku(), 1);
?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $sale_qty > 0): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('In stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php
    else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php
    endif; ?>
<?php
endif; ?>
```

and set your label as your requirement in this phtml.